# Detect any changes made to Django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have found myself in a situation where for several models say `X`, `Y` and `Z`, I would like to know when any change happens on them i.e. any create, update, delete so that I can perform another action. I have scoured the internet but all I get is libs on instance audit history. Is there any way to accomplish this inbuilt in django or even a custom solution/lib would be highly appreciated.

My idea right now is to make these models emit a `post_save` signal and listen for this.

Comment: You don't need to "make the model emit" the signal. Models do that automatically. [The docs say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save): "This is sent at the beginning of a model’s save() method." Same goes for `post_save` and others. You only need to listen to the signals.

Answer (score 1):

[Model signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) are already going to be sent without your having to tell them to be, just as a part of Django models. You can set up [listeners](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/#listening-to-signals) to the signals that are already being sent.

[`pre_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-delete) or [`post_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-delete) will cover your deletion case; [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#pre-save) and [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/signals/#post-save) will handle your update/create. `post_save` sends a `created` argument, which is `True` if a new record was created and `False` otherwise.